# How to import keys and values into variables from a map?

Tags: dictionary, foreach, dart

I need to export the keys and values from map in Dart. In PHP I use for that purpose function `extract()`:

```
$array=array('one'=>1,'two'=>2,'three'=>3);
extract($array);
```

But I don't know, how to do the same thing in Dart. Is there any special function or construct for it? Or how can I reach the same result with forEach()? Is there anybody, who could help me?

---

**Update 1:** My target is from the map like this, but much complicated (example taken from Dart up and running):

```
var gifts = {
// Keys       Values
'first'  : 'partridge',
'second' : 'turtledoves',
'fifth'  : 'golden rings'
};
```

in which I want to rewrite the result by any simple function or forEach() loop:

```
// something like gifts.forEach()? but how?
```

into variables:

```
assert(first=='partridge');
assert(second=='turtledoves');
assert(fifth=='golden rings');
//wow, rewritten! The code can continue and use just the variables:
querySelector('#animal').text=first;
```

Comment: What is extract? What should the result look like?

Comment: As far as I know there is nothing like extract in Dart.

Comment: In PHP `extract()` function gets keys and values from the array and the keys translate into the variables and assings them the values, see my updated question

Comment: @lrn aready provided a qualified answer. I think there is nothing to add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dart is a statically declared language. You cannot create new variable names at runtime, from a map or in any other way.

In order to refer to a variable, it must already be declared. That means that even if you could introduce new variables, you could not have any references to it in your existing code.

If the variables are already declared, and you just want to assign the values to them, you can use the mirror system, but I wouldn't recommend that. It is much simpler to just access the values directly in the map.

Comment: Finally, I made it through mirrors. Thanks for your effort